# How do I successfully Import a humanik Maya character via FBX

Tags: rigging, import

[image: FBX mess]

The image shows the skeleton with all its bones at the correct position but incorrect orientation. Behind that is the character's boot which is lying sideways so either the skeleton is not scaled properly or the character.

Recap:
Need to find out how to get bones to orient properly.
Need to find out how to get the shapes to orient the same direction as the skeleton.
Need to find out how to get everything at the correct scale.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using an alternative FBX importer with good success rate.
You can download the tool and script at http://blenderfbx.render.jp/

The default fbx importer that comes with blender often could not resolve
rigs, and rotation and scale just get screwed. For fbx you will need to download an extra set of software, follow the installation instruction closely. After installing the software and the addon... importing fbx should be a breeze.

**A MORE DETAILED INSTRUCTION** by [Eric huelin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20109/eric-huelin)
Here are the handy concise instructions. You will need:
(Remember to check on the correct versions. This is accurate as on **Feb 2016**)

1 - Visual C++ download here: microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784
2 - UmConverter download here: umconv.render.jp
3 - BL_20150704 download here: blenderfbx.render.jp

Install Visual C++. Open the UmConverter zip folder copy into the blender.exe folder. In Blender File>User Preference>Addons tab>[ Install from file ] Select io_scene_bos_fbx.zip Check the box on the right [ ] [ Save as default ]. When importing goto File>Import>Bos FBX – [Eric huelin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20109/eric-huelin)

Comment: Here are the handy concise instructions:
You need:
<br/>
- Visual C++ 
download here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784
<br/>
- UmConverter
download here: http://umconv.render.jp/
<br/>
- BL_20150704
download here: http://blenderfbx.render.jp/
<br/>
Install Visual C++
<br/>
Open the UmConverter zip folder copy into the blender.exe folder.
<br/>
In Blender File>User Preference>Addons tab>[ Install from file ] Select io_scene_bos_fbx.zip Check the box on the right [ ] 
[ Save as default ]
<br/>
When importing File>Import>Bos FBX

Comment: The io_scene_bos_fbx.zip is inside the downloaded BL_ 20xxxx.zip file.