# FBX files from 3D Studio Max imports with wrong transforms

Tags: transforms, unity, .fbx, origin

Files (in my case sourced from CAD) look ok in 3d Studio Max and Unity, but in Blender, all transforms and origins are wrong (it looks exploded, basically).

I've found two people with the same problems here in the past, but no definitive answer:

[Objects transformations wrong when importing from 3ds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5405/objects-transformations-wrong-when-importing-from-3ds)

[FBX export from 3DS Max 2017](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68600/fbx-export-from-3ds-max-2017)

Edit: Found another similar question, which I'm guessing this is part of the same issue...

[How do I successfully Import a humanik Maya character via FBX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45373/how-do-i-successfully-import-a-humanik-maya-character-via-fbx)

Also, Blender is probably aware, since there's an import option labeled !EXPERIMENTAL! apply transforms, but it doesn't work on any file I tested.

And for the record, Unity imports all these FBX files just fine, and Autodesk's own FBX Converter tool also views these files just fine.

[image: Max on the left, Blender on the right]

Comment: This is a common problem with exporting/importing models from one program to another. It depends upon program used for modeling (origin of model) and program used for importing. It is also greately affected by how you created the model in its origin program, and you have to instantly adopt it for exportation into another. I had many problems with this topic in the past, so if you could upload your file, I can take a look at what the problem is and what can be done. It is simply impossible to answer you before looking at the model. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said, Unity and the official FBX Converter Tool do not have these problems, so it's an issue with Blender's importing implementation. Bug filed here:

https://developer.blender.org/T51807

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but I figured out a workaround for anyone else in the future having this problem. I got this Audi s3 model from cgtrader but it only came in a 3dsmax file. When I went to export/import into blender, it ended up looking like this:
[image: Model straight from 3dsMax to Blender]

For some reason 3dsMax just will not play well with blender as far as fbx exporting/importing, but as Eobet said, it does a fine job with unity. Using this to our advantage, we can download the "FBX Exporter" package for unity, and use it like a translator. The steps are as follows:

-Export from 3dsMax to FBX using default settings:
[image: export window in 3dsmax showing default settings]

-Import the FBX as a new asset into unity (note, the textures might look a bit botched in unity but it will work itself out in blender):
[image: Import new asset window in Unity]

-Add/install the "FBX" Exporter" package from the unity package manager, making sure you change the drop down from "in project" to "unity registry":
[image: "Package Manager" dropdown and window]

-Export from unity to another FBX file by right clicking on the object in the hierarchy and selecting "Export To FBX". VERY IMPORTANT HERE, make sure you switch the export format to BINARY. It will probably default to ASCII (also, it will default the file path to this unity project's asset folder so be sure to change it if you want it elsewhere):
[image: "Export as FBX" dropdown and window]

-Import the new FBX from unity into Blender (keep default settings):
[image: "Import FBX" dropdown and Window]

-Et Voila, your 3dsMax file is imported into blender without being torn to pieces like a bomb went off in it!
[image: Final Result]