# 3ds max to blender, rotations and locations are all wrong

Tags: modeling, import

Everytime I upload my fbx of a car that I had modified in 3ds max (free trial expired, so now I'm using blender), all the rotations and locations for the children get screwed up. All the wheels, doors, etc should be in place, but this is the result in blender:

[image]

If I upload the same fbx into the ue4 engine, everything is fine. Are there any import settings I could try, or anything else? Thanks.

[image: Settings I used]

Comment: Hello, when using *File>Import>Fbx* you have a bunch of settings on the right of the new window. You might have to expand the settings panel with *N* shortcut or click on the little arrow on the top right

Comment: Yes then what? I'm going to update my post to show what settings I used (default).

Comment: Have you tried modifying some of the *Transform* settings ? Without the source file it is hard to fix your problem for you

Comment: Sorry for not responding, but here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFB_6n9Q-zTYTLCHLEI8FNVelmg1TnSd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A couple years late, but I answered this over here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299211/172273